# GetAsyncKeyState working with numbers? Visual Basic

Tags: numbers, detect, keylogger

I'm making a keylogger for myself and I can't understand how to get the numbers working.

```
key1 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.B)
If Key1 = True Then
    RichTextBox1.SelectedText = "B"
End If
```

Can you do this some other way? If so, please let me know!

Thanks! C:

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you to use a little bit more advanced way. First, declare GetAsyncKeyState in your class:

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Short
```

Then, to get the key 1:

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(49)) Then
    'Do something with 1
End If
```

To get numpad key 1:

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(97)) Then
    'Do something with keypad number 1
End If
```

And now you wonder, where do you get these numbers from? Here you can see which numbers is which key: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html Scroll down a little bit and you can see all number to key translation. The numbers you are going to use is the 'Keycode' numbers.

And if you don't want to remember all these numbers, you can create integers which store these numbers, eg.:

```
Dim Key_1 As Integer = 49
```

I hope you don't use this for illegal purposes.

Comment: @user3364046 what about this?